# calculate and return the sum of all the even numbers in the 2d-array in java

Tags: java, sum, multidimensional-array

This Matrix class takes a `int[][]` as a parameter and saves it in
the instance variable.

I need to complete the `sumOfEvenNumbers` method to calculate and return the sum of all the even numbers in the array.

```
public class Matrix
{
    private int[][] matrix;

    /**
     * Gets the sum of all the even numbers in the matrix
     * @return the sum of all the even numbers
     */
    public int sumOfEvenNumbers()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int[] i: array)                          
        if (i%2 == 0){ 
        sum += i;        
        }
        return sum;
         // TODO: Return the sum of all the numbers which are even
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more clear about your question...

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a 2D array, you'll need to iterate through rows and columns:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++)
        if(arr[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            sum += arr[i][j];

return sum;
```

Alternatively, use a for-each to make this even simpler:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int[] innerArr : arr)
    for (int i : innerArr)
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            sum += i;

return sum;
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey What do you mean simpler?

Comment: Simpler than what I wrote at least.  Using for-each would make it simpler again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to apply this to a two d array, 
try using a normal for loop which has a column counter and a row counter, then adding up the sums. 
So basically a for loop inside a for loop. Likewise:

```
for(int col=0; col < matrix.length; col++)
{
  for(int row=0; row < matrix.length; row++)
 {
  //your code to access display[row][col]
 }
}
```

Your current code only supports 1 Dimensional arrays with an enhanced for loop. Enhanced for loops are great for printing output, but not for assigning/checking values - especially in multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Post code please, not just theory. Nice to see new people around :)

Answer (score 1):

Using modulus and branches is expensive and I expect you will find a formula to be quite a bit faster.  Try

```
public long sumOfEvenNumbers() {
    long sum =0;
    for (int[] arr: array)
        for(int i : arr)                          
            sum += (~i & 1) * i;        
    return sum;
}
```

If you have `(i & 1) * i` this will be `0` for even and `i` for odd.  This would effective only add odd numbers.  To flip this for even numbers, we can flip the bits of `i` and use `(~i & 1) * i` which is `0` for odd and `i` for even.

`~i` flips all the bits of `i` and is the same as `i ^ -1` or `-i - 1` or more accurately `-i == ~i + 1`

Comment: Can you explain what `sum += (~i & 1) * i` does? What's the squiggly line doing? :)

Comment: @AnubianNoob added a bit of a break down.

Comment: Dang... How is this better than `%`? It's certainly more unreadable.

Comment: `%` is one of the most expensive integer operations and which you could reduced by using `if((i & 1) == 0)` but branch misses and pretty expensive too. A branch miss is about 4x more expensive than an integer `*`

Comment: Hmm this seems like one of those optimizations that isn't worth it... Readability seems more important here.

Comment: @AnubianNoob I would agree with you there.  I suspect proving it is really better isn't easy.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Perhaps you could use the for-each loops for readability. ;)

Comment: Well it's fair to say this is more efficient, but using modulus is easier to read and understand. * tips hat * Well played sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
package Homeworks;

public class HW89SumEvenIndexEvenRow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] a = {
                {-5,-2,-3,7},
                {1,-5,-2,2},
                {1,-2,3,-4}
        };
        int sum=0;
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i+=1){
            for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
                if(i%2==0 ||j%2==0) {
                    sum=sum+a[i][j];
                }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: /*
   * Write a program that sums all numbers that are on even index and on even row and prints it out.

For example, in the following array, the numbers with parentheses would be summed:

     0  1  2  3

0   (4)(6)(3)(2)
1   (4) 1 (2) 3
2   (1)(2)(6)(9)
   */
  heres the question for the above answer